# Symfony Mapping Error: "The association Entity\Rule#ruleSettings refers to the owning side field Entity\RuleSettings#rules which does not exist."

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine-mapping, symfony-4.4

I would ask why am I getting error

```
 [FAIL] The entity-class AppBundle\Entity\Rule mapping is invalid:
 * The association AppBundle\Entity\Rule#ruleSettings refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\RuleSettings#rules which does not exist.

 [FAIL] The entity-class AppBundle\Entity\RuleSettings mapping is invalid:
 * The association AppBundle\Entity\RuleSettings#targets refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Target#rulesettings which does not exist.
 * The association AppBundle\Entity\RuleSettings#departments refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Department#rulesettings which does not exist.
 * The association AppBundle\Entity\RuleSettings#ruleActions refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\RuleAction#rulesettings which does not exist.

 ...
```

when I call

```
console  doctrine:schema:validate
```

There are my Entities:
Rule

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RuleSettings",mappedBy="rules")
     */
    private $ruleSettings;
```

RuleSettings

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rule")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ruleId",nullable=false)
     */
    private $rule;
```

What problem do I have there?

Answer (score 0):

`mappedBy="rules"` does not equal `$rule`

change to `mappedBy="rule"`